# SherlockBar 4.0 in Android and PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use this library for ActionBar: http://actionbarsherlock.com/ (4.0 beta version)
All work, but I have some questions:

1. There is any variant to create PreferenceFragment? If not, is any variants to create ActionBar with tabs, where one of tabs give a Preferences?
2. To working with tab I use this code: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html
   But it don't work, becouse in ActionBar  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) don't have second parameter. Is any variants to make it work? I not, is any variants to create normal switching tabs?

Comment: Have you tried the example that comes when you download the library? it has the tab bar you are looking for.. also if you look in the image they posted on the home screen, you can see the ActionBar with tabs: http://actionbarsherlock.com/static/feature_03.png

Comment: I'm certainly looking examples. But the examples do not PreferenceFragment, the examples do not have the normal switching tabs (in the examples fragments of tabs each time re-created, but it is not correct). I need to fragments of each tab does not re-create each time, as the user changes something in each fragment during operation.

Answer (score 3):

1. `PreferenceFragment` is not part of the support library from Google which is the source of all fragment-related classes. So, no.
2. Version 4.0 final merged the support-lib plugin back into the core library so the callbacks now include a `FragmentTransaction` parameter.